# ModelState.IsValid is false for sending the Id with hidden input

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I just started learning asp.net core razor pages and building a simple project with a tutorial.
this project has an "Edit" razor page for editing books. and I'm trying to pass the Id of my model(Book) to the post handler with a hidden input because without it the Book.Id would be 0.but when I do it with an asp-for tag helper and hit the Update button for submitting, Model.IsValid is false.
but the Id of the book was passed with URL from the "Index" page when in the "Edit" page I can see the value in URL.
Here is my model:

```
    public class Book
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Author { get; set; }

        public string ISBN { get; set; }
     
     }
```

and my cshtml for Edit:

```
    <h2 class="text-info">Edit Book</h2>

<div class="container border m-3">
    <form method="post">
        <input asp-for="Book.Id" type="hidden"/>
        <div class="row form-group mt-2">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label " asp-for="Book.Title"></label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input asp-for="Book.Title" class="form-control" id="title"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="Book.Title" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row form-group mt-2">
            <label for="author" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label " asp-for="Book.Author"></label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input asp-for="Book.Author" class="form-control" id="author"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="Book.Author" class="text-danger"></span>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row form-group mt-2">
         <label for="ISBN" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label " asp-for="Book.ISBN"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input asp-for="Book.ISBN" class="form-control" id="ISBN"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="Book.ISBN" class="text-danger"></span>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-3 offset-2">
            <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary form-control"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 ">
            <a asp-page="Index" class="btn btn-secondary form-control">Back To List</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
@section scripts{
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

and my cshtml.cs:

```
public class EditModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public EditModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    [BindProperty] 
    public Book Book { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGet(int id)
    {
        await _db.Book.FindAsync(id);
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var bookFromDb = await _db.Book.FindAsync(Book.Id);
            bookFromDb.Title = Book.Title;
            bookFromDb.Author = Book.Author;
            bookFromDb.ISBN = Book.ISBN;

            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToPage("Index");

        }

        return RedirectToPage();

    }


}
```

Comment: In your OnGet you are not setting the Book property to the result of your db call. How are you not getting null exception when the page is loaded? Could this be the issue?

Comment: @MajdOdeh I think that is because in the index page when I hit the Edit button it passes the Id with "asp-route-id" tag helper :
`a asp-page="Edit" asp-route-id="@t.Id" class="btn btn-success text-white btn-sm">Edit Book</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but the Id of the book was passed with URL from the "Index" page when
> in the "Edit" page I can see the value in URL.

`Book` in PageModel will only bind data from **one source**. So it will not bind the data from query string.

**The first way**, If you use hidden input for `Book.Id`, you need set the value for `Book`. Then `Book.Id` will have value otherwise it is empty string when post. Change like below:

```
public async Task OnGet(int id)
{
    Book = await _db.Book.FindAsync(id);
}
```

**Another way**, you could set an `id` as parameter like `OnGet` method, then set the `id` to `Book.Id`:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(int id)
{
    Book.Id = id;
    //...
    return RedirectToPage();
}
```

In this way, hidden input for `Book.Id` is useless:

```
<input asp-for="Book.Id" type="hidden" />
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I do exactly what the instructor does in the tutorial. On the index page for each book there is an "Edit" button with anchor tag like this: 
`a asp-page="Edit" asp-route-id="@t.Id" class="btn btn-success text-white btn-sm">Edit Book</a>`
 this way the id is passed to the "Edit" page with URL.and then in OnPost handler of "Edit" page he passes this Id with hidden input so that the Id is not 0.but when I do this the StateModel.Isvalid becomes false.

Comment: Of course not. You misunderstand model binding and tag helper. `asp-route-id="@t.Id"`  just generate the query string in url in razor pages. It will not bind the value to input. The correct way to bind input values is to set the `Book` value in OnGet method.

Comment: What the tutorial do should be the first way in my answer. You miss set `Book = await _db.Book.FindAsync(id);`. You could check the tutorial.  I am sure it is impossible bind input value by such `asp-route-id`.

Comment: yeah, that was the problem but it was not a good mistake :\ thanks for the help